# how to remove all sent/received/draft messages at once in modem manager gui

Tags: gui

There is no any option provided by modem manager gui to remove all messages at once. Is there any way to delete all messages without hitting del key for each and every message. Thank you!

Comment: I've never heard of this "modem manager gui" (you could improve your question by telling us what it is, where you found it etc) but can't you use Shift or Ctrl to select multiple messages?

Comment: @terdon There's actually [one](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/modem-manager-gui/) that shows "messages" and it's indeed called "Modem Manager GUI". These are SMS messages, not mail messages like I first thought.

Answer (score 0):

If there's really no ability to `shift click` as @terdon suggests, try checking `/home/USER/.cache/modem-manager-gui` for the messages (replace `USER` with your home directory obviously). Then just `rm *.ext` from within that directory (replacing `ext` with the relevant extension).

Comment: no sir, there are only two .conf files.